# Hibernate con sqlite

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite3, sqlite

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio y deseo hacerlo mediante `Sqlite` e `Hibernate`.

¿Sabe alguien si es posible integrar `Hibernate` con `Sqlite3`?

Comment: Sqlite3 no es la mejor opción para producción alguna razón por la que debas integrarlo con Hibernate ?

Comment: El motivo de integrar sqlite3 es no tener que utilizar un servidor de base de datos.

Comment: Podrías probar con esto https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/

Comment: ¿Hay alguna otra mejor opción que no sea mediante un servidor de base de datos?

Comment: @JuanAntonioFernándezDíaz Cuantas tablas necesitas manejar que no quieres implementar un SGBD

Comment: @JuanAntonioFernándezDíaz en que lenguaje estas programando tu app ?

Comment: La base de datos es pequeñas con unas 10 tablas más o menos, pero tablas pequeñas con unos 5 o 6 campos cada una. Programo en Java.

Comment: @JuanAntonioFernándezDíaz aparentemente investigando un poco hibernate como orm no veo mucha documentación sobre SQLite, pero encontré esto tal vez te sea útil http://javalite.io/activejdbc

Comment: @Santi92 El número de tablas no importa mucho, lo que importa es la arquitectura de la aplicación. Si por ejemplo Juan desea hacer un software de escritorio para un único usuario ¿que necesidad hay de agregar un RDBMS?, en cambio si se trata de una aplicación estilo cliente-servidor entonces si podría ser recomendable.

Comment: Es una aplicación solo para un usuario.

Comment: Disculp @user3159253 no entendí tu comentario

Comment: Me dio algo de curiosidad saber si se tiene soporte para integrar Hibernate con Sqlite 3, al parecer no existe como tal. Tal vez una opción será lo que comenta Joel: https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/

Comment: @JuanAntonioFernándezDíaz yo he usado H2 sin problemas con Hibernate, es más o menos lo mismo que SQLite, y es muy fácil de integrar con apps Java.

Comment: La pregunta debe estar orientada a como hacerlo, y no "alguien sabe" que claramente se para debates sin llegar a solución, por favor modificala

Answer (score 2):

**Si**, es posible pero, desde mi *opinión*, no lo recomiendo.

### ¿Por que?

SQLite esta pensado tener soporte nativo de su motor. Para ello es necesario un driver JDBC o usar ODBC. Si es un driver JDBC, es no viene con el SDK de Java SE ni EE.

El driver esta en la pagina oficial de SQLite pero es necesario instalar en cada computadora donde lo vayas a usar y, ademas, no es un driver universal, ya que hay un binario especifico para cada plataforma.

Usar un puente ODBC es poco *performante* y, por ende, tampoco seria una opcion.

### Alternativas viables:

Si lo que estas buscando la portabilidad en tu aplicacion, te recomendaría otro tipo de base de datos embebidas basadas en Java como:

- MS Access (solomente para Windows)
- [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)
- [HSQLDB](http://www.hsqldb.org/)
- [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)
- [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[sqlite-dialect](https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect) es un proyecto que implementa el hibernate dialecto para sqlite. Además se necesita un [jdbc driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) (controlador) para sqlite.

dudo que sea buena idea fiarse de un proyecto tan exótico, pero podría intentarlo.